# C# income tax calculator

Tags: c#

I have 3 text boxes for different rates of income tax

```
20%
40%
45%
```

So Between

```
£11,000 - £43,000   20%
£43,001 - £150,000  40%
150,000+            45%
```

So to calculate the tax between £11,000 and £43,000 I have written an if statement

```
if(Salary > decimal.Parse(noTaxThreshold) && Salary <= decimal.Parse(pc20TaxLimit))
            {
                taxableIncome = Salary - decimal.Parse(noTaxThreshold);
                annualTax = taxableIncome * decimal.Parse(lowerTaxPc);
                tbATax.Text = annualTax.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                tbANetPay.Text = tbAGrossPay.Text;
                tbATax.Text = "0.00";
            }
```

How would I go about figuring out the other amounts for example if the pay was £200,000 per year, then this would have 3 different rates of income tax.

Comment: Why do you have to parse your noTaxThreshold variable?  Is it not a decimal?

Comment: Just a simple if-then-else....

Comment: I did a SqlCommand to get the tax information from another SQL table and then stored the values in variables but couldn't get it to work unless i used string so I had to parse. The threshold is currently £11,000.00 so I thought decimal would be better for money than a double would.

Comment: If your income was £200,000 a year, I'd suggest getting some advice from an accountant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to work backwards and discount the amount you have already calculated tax on. How about:

```cs
public decimal CalculateTax(decimal salary) {
    const int topRateThreshold = 150000;
    const int higherRateThreshold = 43000;
    const int basicRateThreshold = 11000;

    const decimal topRateFactor = 0.45M;
    const decimal higherRateFactor = 0.40M;
    const decimal basicRateFactor = 0.20M;

    decimal salaryWorkingRange = salary;

    decimal taxDue = 0;

    if (salaryWorkingRange > topRateThreshold) {
        taxDue += (salaryWorkingRange - topRateThreshold) * topRateFactor;
        salaryWorkingRange = topRateThreshold;
    }
    if (salaryWorkingRange > higherRateThreshold) {
        taxDue += (salaryWorkingRange - higherRateThreshold) * higherRateFactor;
        salaryWorkingRange = higherRateThreshold;
    }
    if (salaryWorkingRange > basicRateThreshold) {
        taxDue += (salaryWorkingRange - basicRateThreshold) * basicRateFactor;
    }

    return taxDue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't clutter up your code with loads of ifs. What if a new tax band gets created? Try this approach instead:

```
var taxBands = new[]
{
    new { Lower = 0m, Upper = 10999m, Rate = 0.0m },
    new { Lower = 11000m, Upper = 43000m, Rate = 0.2m },
    new { Lower = 43001m, Upper = 150000m, Rate = 0.4m },
    new { Lower = 150001m, Upper = decimal.MaxValue, Rate = 0.45m }
};

var salary = 200000m; // however you get the salary figure

var taxToBePaid = 0m;

foreach (var band in taxBands)
{
    if(salary > band.Lower)
    {
        var taxableAtThisRate = Math.Min(band.Upper - band.Lower, salary - band.Lower);
        var taxThisBand = taxableAtThisRate * band.Rate;
        taxToBePaid += taxThisBand;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(taxToBePaid); // or do whatever you want here
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a flat rate of tax over a certain amount. If so then this should do it:

```
    private decimal CalculateTax(int salary)
    {
        int noTaxThreshold = 11000;
        int band1 = 10999;
        int band2 = 43000;
        int band3 = 150000;

        if (salary < noTaxThreshold) return 0;
        if (salary >= band3) return (salary - noTaxThreshold) * (decimal)0.45;
        if (salary > band2) return (salary - noTaxThreshold) * (decimal)0.40;
        if (salary > band1) return (salary - noTaxThreshold) * (decimal)0.20;
        return 0;
    }
```

Usually through you get taxed in bands, so you only pay 45% tax on the portion you earnt that was *over* 150k

I used an int for the salary as *usually* you get taxed on a rounded amount, you can always change this to a decimal if you need to

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TaxSlab
{
    public int TaxId {get;set;}
    public double MinRangeAmount {get;set;}
    public double MaxRangeAmount {get;set;}
    public int TaxRate {get;set;}
    public double TaxRateAmount {get;set;}

}
  class Program
    {
    static List<TaxSlab> taxSlab= new List<TaxSlab>();

    static void LoadTaxSettings()
    {
        taxSlab.AddRange(new TaxSlab[]{
            new TaxSlab{TaxId=1,MinRangeAmount=0,MaxRangeAmount=250000,TaxRate=0,TaxRateAmount=0},
            new TaxSlab{TaxId=2,MinRangeAmount=250000,MaxRangeAmount=500000,TaxRate=10,TaxRateAmount=250000*10/100},
            new TaxSlab{TaxId=3,MinRangeAmount=500000,MaxRangeAmount=1000000,TaxRate=20,TaxRateAmount=500000*20/100},
            new TaxSlab{TaxId=4,MinRangeAmount=1000001,MaxRangeAmount=999999999,TaxRate=30,TaxRateAmount=2999999*30/100},

          });
    }

    static double GetTaxAmount(double taxableAmount)
    {
        /*          
         return taxSlab.Where(x=>x.MinRangeAmount<taxableAmount).Select(x=> new {Tax=
                                                                            (
                                                                                (x.MinRangeAmount<taxableAmount && taxableAmount<x.MaxRangeAmount) ?
                                                                                Math.Round(((taxableAmount-x.MinRangeAmount)*x.TaxRate/100),0) :
                                                                                Math.Round(x.TaxRateAmount,0)
                                                                            )

                                                                       }).Sum(x=>x.Tax);
        */


         return taxSlab.Where(x=>x.MinRangeAmount<taxableAmount).Select(x=> new {Tax=
                                                                            (
                                                                                (x.MinRangeAmount<taxableAmount && taxableAmount<x.MaxRangeAmount) ?
                                                                                Math.Round(((taxableAmount-x.MinRangeAmount)*x.TaxRate/100),0) :
                                                                                Math.Round((x.MaxRangeAmount-x.MinRangeAmount)*x.TaxRate/100,0)
                                                                            )
                                                                       }).Sum(x=>x.Tax);

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
LoadTaxSettings();
Console.WriteLine("720000 : {0}" ,GetTaxAmount(720000));
Console.WriteLine("750000 : {0}" ,GetTaxAmount(750000));
Console.WriteLine("850000 : {0}" ,GetTaxAmount(850000));
Console.WriteLine("950000 : {0}" ,GetTaxAmount(950000));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually approached this a little more dynamic.

```
public class TaxBracket
{
    public int Low { get; set; }
    public int High { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}

public class TaxCalculator
{
    private readonly int _taxableIncome;
    private readonly TaxBracket[] _taxBrackets;

    public TaxCalculator(int taxableIncome, TaxBracket[] taxBrackets)
    {
        _taxableIncome = taxableIncome;
        _taxBrackets = taxBrackets;
    }

    public decimal Calculate()
    {
        var fullPayTax =
            _taxBrackets.Where(t => t.High < _taxableIncome)
                .Select(t => t)
                .ToArray()
                .Sum(taxBracket => (taxBracket.High - taxBracket.Low)*taxBracket.Rate);

        var partialTax =
            _taxBrackets.Where(t => t.Low <= _taxableIncome && t.High >= _taxableIncome)
                .Select(t => (_taxableIncome - t.Low)*t.Rate)
                .Single();

        return fullPayTax + partialTax;
    }
}
```

It makes any changes easier since we pass in the brackets.